# How to insert React Array data to Mysql with Axios & Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, mysql2

i need to insert a prescription details in mySQL database, but i struggle to inserting it with array data.

I have 2 states,  1 array state to keep the medicines i push into it then send the values to axios when done & 1 state to save the selected medicine.

My options example: using react-select

```
const medicine = [
  { id_obat: '123', label: 'Amoxcilin 300mg' },
  { id_obat: '321', label: 'Ibuprofen 500ml' }
];
```

React codes:

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const [meds, setMeds] = useState({
    obat: {},
    cara_pakai: '',
    kuantitas: ''
  });

  const initialState = {
    obat: {},
    cara_pakai: '',
    kuantitas: ''
  };

  const handleChange = obat => {
    setMeds({ ...meds, ['obat']: obat });
  };

  const addMed = () => {
    setValues([...values, meds]);
    setMeds({ ...initialState });
  };

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addPrescript(values);
  };
```

My axios action to send it to my API:

```
export const addPrescript = values => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

  const form = qs.stringify(values);

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/prescription', form, config);

    dispatch({ type: ADD_PRESCRIPT, payload: res.data });

    dispatch(setAlert('Submit Success', 'success', 3000));
  } catch (err) {
    let errors = err.response.data.errors;
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }
  }
};
```

My prescription controller:

```
exports.createPrescription = async (req, res) => {
  const { id_obat, cara_pakai, kuantitas, deskripsi } = req.body;

  const p_value = {
    deskripsi: deskripsi
  };

  const p_sql = 'INSERT INTO resep SET ?';
  const d_sql = 'INSERT INTO detail_resep SET ?';

  conn.query(p_sql, p_value, (error, p_result) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    let d_value = [
      {
        id_resep: p_result.insertId,
        id_obat: id_obat,
        cara_pakai: cara_pakai,
        kuantitas: kuantitas
      }
    ];
    conn.query(d_sql, [d_value], (error, d_result) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.status(200).json({
        values: d_result
      });
    });
  });
};
```

My backend server keep sending me error [You have an error in your SQL syntax], i dont know how to solve it.

my API required req.body to submit is | id_resep | id_obat | cara_pakai | kuantitas | to be success inserted. i dont know if im wrong with the stringify. my first time work with array data :>

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

look like below statement has to change

```
const p_sql = 'INSERT INTO resep SET ?';
const d_sql = 'INSERT INTO detail_resep SET ?';
```

to

```
const p_sql = 'INSERT INTO resep( {columnname}) values({value1,value2})';
const d_sql = 'INSERT INTO detail_resep ( {columnname}) values({value1,value2}))';
```

change {columnname } to your column name and corresponding values in {value}

Basically insert statement syntax is not correct here.